# Combine two datasets covering all the possible combinations

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse

I have issues in performing a join operation.

My two dataframes are:

```
library(tidiverse)
df_one <- data.frame(
                cohort = c("2019-03-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01",
                           "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01"),
               periods = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
                 value = c(13, 24, 35, 22, 38, 21)
          )

df_two <- data.frame(
               periods = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
               value_2 = c(100, 73, 45, 29)
          )
```

The final result I want to achieve is a joined dataframe that contains all the possible combinations in `df_two` - repeated for the elements in `df_one` - as follows:

```
df_final <- data.frame(
                  cohort = c("2019-03-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-01",
                             "2019-04-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-04-01",
                             "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01",
                             "2019-05-01"),
                 periods = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                   value = c(13, 24, 35, NA, 22, 38, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, NA),
                 value_2 = c(100, 73, 45, 29, 100, 73, 45, 29, 100, 73, 45, 29)
            )

       cohort periods value value_2
1  2019-03-01       1    13     100
2  2019-03-01       2    24      73
3  2019-03-01       3    35      45
4  2019-03-01       4    NA      29
5  2019-04-01       1    22     100
6  2019-04-01       2    38      73
7  2019-04-01       3    NA      45
8  2019-04-01       4    NA      29
9  2019-05-01       1    21     100
10 2019-05-01       2    NA      73
11 2019-05-01       3    NA      45
12 2019-05-01       4    NA      29
```

I attempted the use of `crossing()`:

```
crossing(df_one, df_two)
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: Column name `periods` must not be duplicated.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Once fixed for the unique column names - as suggested by the user @akrun - via:

```
crossing(df_one, df_two, .name_repair = "unique")
```

I realize that `crossing()` won't yield to my desired result.

WHat approach should I follow to get `df_final`?

Comment: I didn't mean to make anybody look like fool. My question was how get the output `df_final` starting from the two initial dataframes `df_one` and `df_two`. I attempted to solve it with `crossing()` - wrongly - and I asked for help with absolutely no intention to offend anybody @akrun

Comment: I edited again the question - specifying your correction relative to the error thrown by `crossing()`, I hope now it clarifies better my request @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crossing` requires unique column names, 'periods' is duplicated.  According to `?crossing`

> crossing(..., .name_repair = "check_unique")

It implies that the default option will check for unique column names and if there are duplicates, it will throw an error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
```

We can either change the `.name_repair` to force column names to 'unique'

```
crossing(df_one, df_two, .name_repair = "unique")
#New names:
#* periods -> periods...2
#* periods -> periods...4
# A tibble: 24 x 5
#   cohort     periods...2 value periods...4 value_2
#   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2019-03-01           1    13           1     100
# 2 2019-03-01           1    13           2      73
# 3 2019-03-01           1    13           3      45
# 4 2019-03-01           1    13           4      29
# 5 2019-03-01           2    24           1     100
# 6 2019-03-01           2    24           2      73
# 7 2019-03-01           2    24           3      45
# 8 2019-03-01           2    24           4      29
# 9 2019-03-01           3    35           1     100
#10 2019-03-01           3    35           2      73
# … with 14 more rows
```

Or use "minimal" where the duplicate column names will be preserved as such (but that would further complicate things in the long run

---

To get the expected, we can do a group by `complete` on the first dataset and then with `left_join` on the second one

```
df_one %>% 
   group_by(cohort) %>%
   complete(periods = df_two$periods) %>%
   left_join(df_two)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   cohort [3]
#   cohort     periods value value_2
#   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2019-03-01       1    13     100
# 2 2019-03-01       2    24      73
# 3 2019-03-01       3    35      45
# 4 2019-03-01       4    NA      29
# 5 2019-04-01       1    22     100
# 6 2019-04-01       2    38      73
# 7 2019-04-01       3    NA      45
# 8 2019-04-01       4    NA      29
# 9 2019-05-01       1    21     100
#10 2019-05-01       2    NA      73
#11 2019-05-01       3    NA      45
#12 2019-05-01       4    NA      29
```

Comment: I understand how crossing works. But probably it is not the right solution since it doesn't end up giving me  my desired `df_final`. Should I use a different function? @akrun

Comment: @xxxvincxxx i thought your question was how to change the error.  Anyway

Comment: Im sorry for the misunderstanding. I tried to attempt the use of `crossing` getting an error, but now looking at the result I realize this is the wrong approach. I am editing the question accordingly.